Prettier does not work in <script> tag in handlebars (hbs) file
My FE using handlebars (hbs) file and Prettier work pretty well except <script> tag of handlebars file
enter image description here
Has anyone encounted this issue?

Why do you expect prettier to work with handlebars. AFAIK prettier doesn't support handlebars, only glimmer.
